# Moving files using wildcard in Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, wildcard

In Windows cmd, I'm trying to move some .avi files from child directories to parent directories. For example, I have a parent directory that contains 5 child directories. And each child directory has one .avi file in it. Let's say the full path of the parent directory is C:\Grand\Parent.

- Parent

  - Child1
  - Child2
  - Child3
  - Child4
  - Child5

With C:\Grand as my working directory, I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
move "Parent\*\*.avi" "Parent"
```

Comment: Do you want to move **all** `.avi`s under `parent` or only those which are in the directories directly under `parent` (not those 2 or more directories below `parent` ?)

Comment: @Magoo Just the .avi files that are in the child directories. Either way, it doesn't really matter because Parent only contains Child directories.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%"'
  ) DO (
 ECHO(MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a\*.avi" "%sourcedir%\"
)

echo============
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.avi" '
  ) DO (
 IF /i "%%~dpa" neq "%sourcedir%\" ECHO(MOVE "%%~fa" "%sourcedir%\"
)
echo============
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.avi"') DO (
 MOVE "%%~fa" "%sourcedir%\" 2>NUL >nul
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Three different methods here - **warning** the third actually performs the `move`.

The first strictly moves the one level below the source to the target.

The second does the same, but with all levels to "flatten" the tree.

The third uses a dirty method - suppressing the errors when `cmd` is instructed to move a file over itself.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line use one of these:

This one might complain if files named `"*.avi"` already exist in `"C:\Grand\Parent"`:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %f in (`dir /s /b /a-d "C:\Grand\Parent\*.avi"`) do move "%~f" "C:\Grand\Parent"
```

This one doesn't process files already in `"C:\Grand\Parent"`:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %f in (`dir /b /ad "C:\Grand\Parent\*"`) do move "%~f\*.avi" "C:\Grand\Parent"
```